# Which double click service i have to use?

Tags: vast

I got a task to implement vast player in android app. I follow ima3 tutorial with sample link and my player works.
The problem is - where to get actually a VAST link to my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have your own Sales and Adops team, get in touch with a company to market and sell your inventory.

Comment: What do you refer as inventory? My target not to sell ads, but monetize my app

Comment: Inventory means your traffic or the users of your app. To monetize you need advertisement and ads are usually sold and handles by a Sales team or Adops, alternatively, you may want to sign up with an ad exchange or join an ad network. You can get a a "VAST tag" that way to implement and show whatever ads the exchange currently has in rotation.